# Is there any value in correlating a binary dependent variable and categorical independent variables?

Tags: correlation, categorical-data, binary-data, dependent-variable

I'm constructing a logit model with a binary dependent variable (probability of exiting unemployment). On the right hand side (independent variables), I have a few continuous variables and a number of categorical variables (e.g. race, job industry, marital status). My question is, is there any value to calculating the correlation between my binary dependent variable and my categorical variables? Intuitively it does not seem like it would make sense to me.

Comment: It looks like you want to perform a fixed effects logistic model. A quick google search revealed [this](https://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/stats3/Panel03-FixedEffects.pdf) document that describes your situation nicely. Good luck.

Comment: If the dependent variables are put in the regression model, categorical variables will be transformed into dummy variables, and multicollinearity can be further investigated.

Comment: @FannieY, I think you mean _independent variables_. See also my comment on your question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/355339/can-chi-sq-test-be-used-to-explore-the-independence-of-categorical-variables-on

Comment: The correlation between two binary variables makes perfect sense so long as the two values (say 0 and 1) are present for both variables. Just imagine a scatter plot with four possible data points (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0) and (1, 1). So, for example, if all values are either (0, 0) or (1, 1) then a straight line summarizes the data perfectly and the correlation is 1. And so on.

Comment: Correlation between a binary response and a more general categorical predictor is better just thought in terms of the behaviour of the logistic regression as a whole.